# How does the "Control Frame Attack" bypass the MAC-Randomization on Smartphones?

Tags: privacy, mac-address, smartphone

[In this Study regarding MAC-Randomization of different Smartphone Manufactures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.02874v1.pdf) on page 15 the so called Control Frame Attack is described. I'm not sure whether I understand this correctly. Are they sending out the RTS to all possible MAC-Addresses while also changing their own MAC? So a device will reply as soon as the attacker hit the global unique MAC, and will answer with the MAC of the RTS sender, so the attacker just has to check what Pair of MAC's where used? This is like the only way this attack makes sense to me, although this sounds way to time consuming and easy detectable. The attack could work that way, but I doubt that this is necessary. I'm pretty sure I missed something because there is not a single word in the study indicating they performed something brute-force-like.

I think I undestood the basics of this vulnerability. As far as i understand it, a device performing randomization will reply to an RTS addressing it's global unique MAC. But the problem I see now is that the CTS is only containing the Receiver Address(RA) [as described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11_RTS/CTS) (as i understand the address of the device that send the RTS). Or is the RA always the Target of the RTS, because it will usually receive a package after the RTS/CTS? I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Can anyone explain to me how exactly this is working?

Is this derandomization approach still possible and as hard(impossible) to fix as described in the study?